# Accessing overrriden public property in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

This is the scenario:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Prop {get; set;}
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string Prop {get; set;}
}

//program
...
ChildClass instance = new ChildClass;
Console.WriteLine(instance.Prop); //accessing ChildClass.Prop
...
```

The question is how to access BaseClass.Prop in a instance of ChildClass? Will casting do the trick?

```
Console.WriteLine((instance as BaseClass).Prop); //accessing BaseClass.Prop
```

-EDIT-
A lot of people suggested casting. In C++ it would not work because polymorphism would still ensure that the child property is called. Isn't that the case in C#?

In C++ you would solve the issue by doing:

```
instance.(BaseClass::get_Prop())
```

Comment: In response to your casting edit, there is a difference in C# between the use of override which then takes advantage of polymorphism in the c++ sense (though you'd have to declare your BaseClass.Prop as virtual). The "new" keyword in c# allows you to declare a property w/the same name as one is a base class. This is obviously a less common case. The current code you have (no modifier on Base, override modifier on Child) won't compile. You should be getting the "cannot override inherited member... because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of overriding a property won't let you access the base of an overridden property. And this makes sense. Classes that use ChildClass shouldn't care if the property is overridden or not. When the property is used by another class it's up to ChildClass to return the appropriate value.

Usually questions like these indicate an attempt to solve a different problem. What kind of problems are you facing that you need direct access to the base property?

Answer (score 3):

Cast the instance of ChildClass to an instance of BaseClass; i.e. use:

```
((BaseClass)childClassInstance).Prop
```

Comment: Isn't polymorphism still supposed to call the child property in tha case?
I'm basing myself in C++ here, maybe C# is different. If so, can someone point that out?

Comment: @David: the cast works because of what is likely to be a mistake in the original code; the property is in fact not overridden.

Comment: In C#, you have control over polymorphism in this instance; if you give the property/method the "new" keyword, then casting to the base class calls the base class implementation. But if you give the property/method the "override" keyword, the derived class implementation will always be called no matter what.

Comment: This is a library Class, it does not have the new keyword in there and I can't add it. So what you are saying is that my problem has no solution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you get a compiler error for that code?

In any case, ChildClass.Prop does not override BaseClass.Prop - it hides it. You should really declare it as

```
    public new string Prop {get; set;}
```

You can access any member from the base class via `base.Member`. In this case, `base.Prop`.

Comment: No compiler error -- "new" is assumed.  He might get a compiler warning, though.

Comment: Ahah. I guess I've been thinking of a message from ReSharper.

Comment: I mean override to be there. I just added it.

Comment: @Beaud: what is new in 3.0? The "new" keyword has been there since Day 1.

Comment: @David: I'm _certain_ your change will produce a compiler error, since base.Prop is not virtual.

Comment: @John: I though he was talking about Automatic Properties: get; set;. My bad :|

Comment: I mixed up things I think, you're the one that mentioned the compiler error and I though I was answering a comment. haha, ah well!

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(((BaseClass)instance).Prop); //BaseClass.Prop
```

This works because the property isn't overridden, it's hidden.  If you added the "`override`" keyword to the derived class property, it would no longer work.

Comment: I meant ovveride to be there. I just added it.

Comment: So what you mean is that it is impossible to access teh base property?

Comment: It's impossible if you're overriding it with another property, yes.  If you use the "new" keyword instead, then you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
BaseClass baseInstance = instance as BaseClass;
Console.WriteLine(baseInstance .Prop); //accessing BaseClass.Prop
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ChildClass's Prop property is hiding BaseClass's Prop property.  This should be a compiler warning.

EDIT:
You'll have to decide which behavior you want, polymorphism or new property declaration, since c# allows for both.

- use virtual/override for polymorphic behavior
- use new for "new-but-same-name" property behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new` keyword along with the `conversion` and it should work

such as `public new string Prop { [...] }`
and `Console.WriteLine((instance as BaseClass).Prop);`

Answer (score -2):

Just like for any base member: base.Prop

Comment: The code accessing the property is not inside the class, so base is no good!